# dimension of spaces of rational curves in a variety!

Tags: algebraic-curves, ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Do you know calculate the dimension of the space of rational curves of degree
m, through d given points, contained in some projective variety?

Comment: The question seems a bit broad, since there is a large body of work on this topic. Anyway, the short answer is "no": for instance, it is not even known in general how to prove that lines on a Fano hypersurface (through d=0 points) have the expected dimension. But you can look at papers of Beheshti, Landsberg, Starr and others to find positive results in this direction. (Hopefully the last-named author will be along presently to give you a more complete answer.)

Comment: @Artie: I like your answer.